# What matrix A with dimension n x n is always true given A - A^2 = O

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

What matrix A with dimension n x n is **always true** given A - A^2 = O where O is the zero matrix with dimension n x n and *I* with dimension n x n is the identity matrix.

A) A is a diagonal matrix
B) A = A^2
C) A = *I*
D) A = O
E) *I* = A^2

Just got out of an exam with this question and I chose B. I thought about this question for a little bit longer after I handed in my exam and I came to the conclusion that A = I.

A - A^2 = O
A = A^2
AA^-1 = (A^-1)(A^2)
*I* = A

Can someone confirm if this is right?

Comment: What is the definition of a "direction matrix"?

Comment: You can only say that $A = I$ if $A$ is non-singular.  Note that $A = O$ also satisfies this equation.

Comment: Oops, it's suppose to be "diagonal matrix"

Comment: Should this say "What _statement about a_ matrix $A$ with dimension $n\times n$ is always true..."?

Comment: Or perhaps "What _statement about a_ matrix $A$ with dimension $n\times n$ _would_ always _make it_ true _that_..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the other answers have misinterpreted the question.  My understanding is  that the question asks:

> Given that $A$ is a matrix satisfying $A - A^2 = 0$, which of the following is always true?

The only correct answer to this question is B.  Certainly, if $A = A^2$, then we can say that
$$
A = (A - A^2) + A^2 = 0 + A^2 = A^2
$$
As a counterexample to all of the other choices, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$

Comment: The question may be so trivial? Unbeliveable!

Answer (score 2):

It is right (answer C, the proof needs a little modification), but D) is also true.
A counterexample to E):
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And for example $2I$ is a counterexample to A).

*Edit:*
And corected version of your proof:
$A - A^2 = O$,
$A = A^2$,
and now, instead of

$AA^{-1} = (A^{-1})(A^2)$

either $AA^{-1} = A^2(A^{-1})$ or $A^{-1}A = (A^{-1})(A^2)$

and finally
$I = A$.

Comment: But is D always true?

Comment: @Wade If $A$ is zero matrix, so is $A^2$.

Comment: I could say the same if A is an identity matrix. So would both C and D be correct?

Comment: @Wade Yes, they are. And the argument is simplier than yours. (Well, in fact, you should multiply by $A^{-1}$ either on left or on right).

Answer (score 0):

I  think $B$, $C$ and $D$ are all correct.

Infact $B$ is the question rewritten in another way.
And as already established $C$ and $D$ are correct.

Comment: This was a multiple choice question. Is there one answer that is more correct than the other?

Comment: @Wade It depends on the rules of your exam. The correct answer is B), C), D), but subset of it may be partially scored.